# one of multiple onload in Javascript does not working in the same page

Tags: javascript, php

Good day guys, I have a question to ask

[image]

From this code, I have included 2 PHP pages and combined into the same page.
As you can see, my `time.php`  consist of `onload=display_ct()` which load time from the server. In other hand, my `test3.php` consist of `window.onload = function() {  scrollDiv_init();};` which load the auto scrolling text. Both are working well ONLY if they are locate in separate page. Otherwise, only one of them will work.My question is, is that possible to make multiple onload to work in 1 page and can you guys provide the solution?

**Updated**

After some edit, I found that both work when I'm swapping them. I have no idea how it happened. Still, it not overcome my problem.

Swap
[image]

Not Swap
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because the latter one is replacing the earlier ones. `onload` is a property that accepts a single function. To add multiple callbacks, consider using `addEventListener` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to execute both of the other functions. For example:

JS

```
function onload(){
    window.setTimeout(function1(), 0);
    window.setTimeout(function2(), 0);
}
```

HTML

```
<body onload="onload()">
    ...
</body>
```